# Why is X-editable datepicker value format different?

Tags: javascript, php, date, date-format, x-editable

i'm using **X-editable extension** for a date input with validation:

```
$('.editable-date').editable({
        type: 'date',
        pk:1,
        params: function(params){
            params.dataId = dataId;
            return params;
        },
        validate : function(value){
            return "value is "+value; //validation 
        },
        url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("/rga/controller/update"); ?>',
        success: function(response){

        }
    });
```

and In the controller for the submit:

```
public function actionUpdate(){
    if(isset($_POST['value'])){
       $dataId = $_POST['dataId'];
       $value = $_POST['value'];
       ChromePhp::log($value); //output value to console      
    //some code here
    }
}
```

the **Chrome log displays the date in yyyy/mm/dd format ( example 2014-24-02 )**
but in the validate code in the JavaScript; when i try to **output the date. it's in a different format,** the return string outputs some kind of :

> value is Sun Jun 29 2014 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard
>   Time)

I need to do some code for validation, but I need to do it in the **yyyy/mm/dd** format. Why is the **date format different in the validate and submit?** And if ever how do i convert the date string to the format i need? Is there a php/javascript function for this? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `value` being returned is a [JavaScript `Date` instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). You should be able to use the Date methods to access the date in another format, for example:

```
validate : function(value){
    var month = ("0" + (value.getMonth()+1).toString()).slice(-2); // The getMonth() method returns the month (from 0 to 11) for the specified date
    var day = ("0" + value.getDate().toString()).slice(-2);
    var year = value.getFullYear().toString();
    var date = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
},
```

Note the `slice`s to add zero-padding for single-digit days and months.